# Sending and Receiving File Strings in ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.15.2

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

I have to send huge files through ActiveMQ and for that purpose I followed the documentation provided [for large messages](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/large-messages.html), but it is throwing error, **packing the file in BytesMessage**.

What is the correct approach for sending file in ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.15.2?

```java
BytesMessage message = session.createBytesMessage();
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(txFile);
BufferedInputStream bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
message.setObjectProperty("JMS_AMQ_InputStream", bufferedInput);
producer.send(message);
```

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Exception:**

```
Caught: javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Only objectified primitive objects, String, Map and List types are allowed but was: java.io.BufferedInputStream@445958d type: class java.io.BufferedInputStream
javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Only objectified primitive objects, String, Map and List types are allowed but was: java.io.BufferedInputStream@445958d type: class java.io.BufferedInputStream
at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage.checkValidObject(ActiveMQMessage.java:538)
at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage.setObjectProperty(ActiveMQMessage.java:504)
at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage.setObjectProperty(ActiveMQMessage.java:488)
at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQBytesMessage.setObjectProperty(ActiveMQBytesMessage.java:918)
at com.svm.mq.test.Producer.run(Producer.java:80)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you pasted (i.e. setting the `JMS_AMQ_InputStream` object property) is for the ActiveMQ **Artemis** Core client.  That won't work for ActiveMQ "Classic."

If you want to "send" a large message with ActiveMQ "Classic" then you will need to use a "blob" message as noted by another user.  However, this still requires you to send the actual message using another method.  The "blob" message is really just a kind of pointer or reference to the message.

Answer (score 0):

Blob Messages is your way to go. Try this [link](http://activemq.apache.org/blob-messages.html) for more details:

```
BlobMessage message = session.createBlobMessage(new File("/foo/bar");
producer.send(message);
```